# Objective C typedef Enum memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, enums, dealloc, alloc

Do I have to take care of memory when I deal with the enum ?
This is where I declared my enum type. It is in another .h file
This is where I attempt to declare variable
After that Do I have o do something like that

```
// This is where I declared my enum type. It is in another .h file

    typedef enum CardTypes
    {
        HEART = 1,
        DIAMOND =2,
        CLUB =3,
        SPADE = 4

    } CardType;

    // This is where I attempt to declare variable  

    CardType cardType=SPADE;

    //or

    CardType cardType=malloc(size(CardType));

    // After that Do I have o do something like that

    [cardType release]

    //or

     free(&card)

     Any help will be appreciated , thanks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a basic C type - and it's handled just like an `int` in this regard.

This is automatic:

```
CardType cardType=SPADE;
```

But when you find you must use `malloc`, then you would need to `free` it.

Typically (e.g. parameter, ivar, local variable), you would declare the enum by value, but (like `int`) you may occasionally need to use `malloc`+`free`.

Answer (score 1):

CardType type = SPADE - Allocates memory on stack (no memory management needed)

CardType *type = malloc(sizeof(CardType)) - allocates memory on heap (mention a pointer *), because of explicit alloction you are responsible of freeing memory using free(type)